# Is it possible to retrieve your source code from heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

Once you have uploaded your source code to Heroku, is it possible to download it from there if necessary such as in the case of a failure of your local disk?

Because of heroku's integration with git, I would assume this might be possible at least in theory.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are correct, you can do a "git clone", there are [Heroku specific directions](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2008/3/3/api_and_external_git_access/) for local editing as well.

Comment: Recent changes are such that `heroku git:clone` is only useful for applications that are deployed with Heroku's hosted git service. In effect this means that applications deployed via GitHub, DropBox or "Deploy to Heroku" buttons will result in an empty repo when cloned.

In that case, you'll need to download the source repository and add the heroku remote to that repo. Once you've done that you can push with git (`git push heroku master`) and you'll be able to clone the repo after that.

Comment: Also one thing I noticed is that I had to include the files individually. To avoid the git objects this caused a bunch of hassled. But once I copied all of the files to the folder everything worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks @conor909, can you add that as an actual answer to this question?

Answer (score 42):

Just go to https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/YOUR_APP_NAME/deploy/heroku-git.

**Install the Heroku Toolbelt**

[Download and install the Heroku Toolbelt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)

If you haven't already, log in to your Heroku account and follow the prompts to create a new SSH public key.

```
$ heroku login
```

**Clone the repository**

Use Git to clone YOUR_APP_NAME's source code to your local machine.

```
$ heroku git:clone -a YOUR_APP_NAME
$ cd YOUR_APP_NAME
```

**Deploy your changes**

Make some changes to the code you just cloned and deploy them to Heroku using Git.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 12):

Just run the following, and you'll be good to go:

```
git clone git@heroku.com:your_app_name.git
```

Comment: Permission denied (publickey)
[fatal]

Comment: warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

Answer (score 9):

For the next person that comes across this and did not deploy using git, https://help.heroku.com/FZDDCBLB/how-can-i-download-my-code-from-heroku

> Downloading the application slug
>
> If you have not used git to deploy your application, or using `heroku git:clone`
>   has only created an empty repository, you can download the
>   slug that was build when you application was last deployed. First,
>   install the heroku-slugs CLI plugin with `heroku plugins:install heroku-slugs`, 
>   then run: 
>   `heroku slugs:download -a APP_NAME`
>
> This will download and compress your slug into a directory with the
>   same name as your application.

Answer (score 7):

First download and install heroku CLI.

Then run this command:

```
heroku login
```

Login by using your username and password.

Then `git clone` by using:

```
heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME
```

**** OR ****

1) Login to heroku : https://id.heroku.com/

2)  select your app.

3) Select Deploy option.

Here you will get all the details with commands for getting the source code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install the heroku Toolbelt.

2nd, generate SSH key by the command: `heroku keys:add`

3rd, clone your repo: `git clone git@heroku.com:__your_repo__.git`